# Passing by value and by pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

This is usual question, but I can't make it work.

This is prototype of function: 
`void QSerialPort::setPort(const QSerialPortInfo &serialPortInfo)`
and I am trying to use it, like this:

```
QSerialPortInfo *serialPortInfo = new QSerialPortInfo("H");
QSerialPort *SerialPort=new QSerialPort;
SerialPort->setPort( &serialPortInfo);
```

As I understand it in prototype we have reference to object, but I have a pointer to QSerialPortInfo, so I anyway us &. It all doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since your `serialPortInfo` is of type `QSerialPortInfo*`,  `&serialPortInfo` is of type `QSerialPortInfo**`.

Comment: You dereference pointers with `*`, not `&`. Also, why are these pointers to dynamic memory in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QSerialPortInfo should not be dynamically allocated (this is not really QT-way, I know).

In your case it should be `SerialPort->setPort(*serialPortInfo)` since you need to dereference your pointer to pass variable by reference.

But this code should be written like here:

```
QSerialPortInfo serialPortInfo("COM1");
QSerialPort* SerialPort = new QSerialPort;
SerialPort->setPort(serialPortInfo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I know, that the name is wrong, I run it on Linux and since I didn't know correctly the port I used this "H". 
As for dynamical allocation I did not know this is not optimal way..

Comment: @Ivan Rule of thumb - avoid new if it is possible. In QT sometimes you cannot do this, but always try to.